# Sed command for merging multiple files

Tags: sed

I want to merge multiple files to single file,  and also remove the header and footer for all files except the first file header and last file footer.

For example I have 10 files:

File1

```
Name
A
B
C
Next date
```

File2

```
Name
D
E
F
Next date
```

...

File10

```
Name
X
Y
Next date
```

I need output like:

```
Name
A
B
C
D
E
F
...
X
Y
Next date
```

How to do in `sed` command?

Comment: Also would be nice to show that how you tried to do it and what didn't work.

Comment: Are you limited to `sed` only?

Comment: Header & Footer in all files are always same and static or have any specific pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `head`, `tail` and `sed`:

```
set -- File*

{
    head -n 1 "$1"
    for file do
        sed '1d;$d' "$file"
    done
    tail -n 1 "$file"
} >outfile
```

This assumes that all the relevant files' names are matched by `File*` (or whatever pattern you use to match them with in the `set` command).

The `set` command sets the positional parameters, i.e. `$1`, `$2` etc., to the filenames that we'd like to work with.  These are also available in the list `$@`.

The `head` command starts by extracting the header from the first file.

The following `sed` command in the loop (which iterates over all files that were matched by `File*`) then outputs the contents of each file, except for the first and last line of each file.  The `sed` expression `1d` deletes the first line of input, and `$d` deletes the last line.

The final `tail` outputs the footer from the last file.

All output is redirected to a file called `outfile`.

Testing with four files, each with a single line header and footer:

```
$ cat File*
FIRST HEADER
1
2
3
FOOTER
HEADER
1
2
3
FOOTER
HEADER
1
2
3
FOOTER
HEADER
1
2
3
LAST FOOTER
```

Running the commands from above. And then,

```
$ cat outfile
FIRST HEADER
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
LAST FOOTER
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Kindly try with below steps and it worked fine

step1:

for i in file1 file2.........filen; do sed -i -e '1d' -e '$d' $i;cat $i >>final_file; done

step2

sed -i '1i Name' final_file

step3

sed '$s/.*/&\nNext date/g' final_file
```

Comment: Note that this modifies the original files, and that the question specifically asked that the header and footer should be taken from the first and last file (you are giving an explicit header and footer text).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this awk :

```
cat script_awk 
NR == 1 {
# keep first header in a
  a = $0
  next
}
FNR == 1 {
# remove last line of File_n and header of File_n+1 
  a=""
  next
}
{
if ( a )
# print previous line
  print a
# keep last line in a
  a=$0
}
END {
# print the last line (footer of last File)
  print a
}
```

and call it this way :

```
awk -f script_awk File1 File2 File10
```

You can call it this way :

```
awk -f script_awk File*
```

but not sure you get the footer of File10